# ¿Como filtrar datos por fecha en una funcion de flecha?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

tengo lo siguiente, como se puede observar solo tengo eso, es que no se por donde comenzar la funcion para filtrar la fecha, porque no se si tengo que obtener la fi,ff y pasarlas a tipo date o algo por el estilo asi que agradeceria, si me pueden colaborar con algunas opiniones y sugernecias :

```
router.get('/ruta/:id/:fi/:ff', async(req, res) => {
    const fecha_inicio = req.params.fi;
    const fecha_fin = req.params.ff;
    let ejemplo= await crud.findOne('ejemplo', 'id', req.params.id);
    const asientos = asiento.filter(function );
    res.json(asientos);
});
```

Comment: que es el findOne, supongo que es mongoDB  y luego quieres aplicar un filtro de fecha; que tal si haces la busqueda directamente con mongodb asi no tienes que volver a recorrerlo

Comment: voy a checar. a ver a y ps es filtrar el ejemplo, lo que pasa es que lo quiero desde la función para mas cómodo para el cliente, ps es el que selecciona el rango de fechas, bueno así es como yo lo pensé.

Comment: como lo tienes no te funcionara, debes cambiar el findOne por find, findOne te traera un objeto o nada, find te traera todos aquellos que cumplen la condicion}